# Inline code not being interpreted correctly when in server-side attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, controls

Take the following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" title='<%=Resources.Constants.EmptyFirstName%>' /><em>*</em>
```

This actually generates a title attribute of `<%=Resources.Constants.EmptyFirstName%>` rather than executing the code (hence returning the correct value).

Is there any reason for this? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply set the attribute value in the code behind file?

```
txtFirstName.Attributes.Add("title",Resources.Constants.EmptyFirstNam);
```

Comment: I went with this one - I didn't realise there was an attributes property

Answer (score 1):

Server side controls cannot use interpreted tags '<%= %>'.  It is easier to just set the value in the code behind, but if you really want the logic in the aspx, you can use data binding expressions:

On your aspx, change your tag to a databinding tag:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" title='<%#=EmptyName()%>' /><em>*</em>
```

Add this function in your code behind:

```
public string EmptyName() {
    return Resources.Constants.EmptyFirstName
}
```

This is cumbersome since you would still need to call `txtFirstName.DataBind()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the value in OnInit in CodeBehind-file?

Comment: Simply because an `asp:TextBox` doesn't have a title attribute but when adding like this it gets rendered on the client (whereas I'd get a compiler error)

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to do this in the aspx file as opposed to the code behind, check out this article on Expression Builders: https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx